# With one variable make another one bigger but make the first one smaller

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, global

I want to make it so when I upgrade the level goes up but the clicks go down by the upgrade cost but when I do it gives me this error:

```
line 19, in upgrade
    if clicks >= 10: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'clicks' referenced before assignment
```

Here's the code:

```
def counter():
    global clicks
    for i in range(0, level):
        clicks += 1
    score.config(text="Score: " + str(clicks))

def upgrade():
    global level
    if clicks >= 10:
        level += 1
        clicks -= 10
    levelLabel.config(text="Upgrade: " + str(level))
```

Comment: Can you post the full script?  The position of where the variables are declared are important.

Comment: The problem was solved, I just forgot to put global clicks in the upgrade function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see that `global clicks` at the beginning of the first function? You have to do it also in the other function, **provided that** a `clicks` variable exists in `global` scope.

---

```
global x

def foo():
    x = 42

def bar():
    global x
    x = 42

x = 69
foo()
print(x) # 69
bar()
print(x) # 42
```

Comment: If it worked consider accepting my answer, feel free to ask in the comments for more information